# Getting error when trying to find element by xpath - System.InvalidOperationException: String cannot be cast to WebElement?

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am getting error on select2 element " System.InvalidOperationException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
" when trying to select value from it. It's strange that sometimes test passes and I am not having problems on other select2 elements for which I use the same code. What can be the problem here?

```
    Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='s2id_State']/a/span[2]/b")).Click();
    Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#select2-drop input.select2-input")).SendKeys("1000");
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[text()='1000']"), "1000")); //Error line
    Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[text()='1000']")).Click();

Result StackTrace:  


  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass26.<TextToBePresentInElementLocated>b__25(IWebDriver driver)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   at Automated.Test.Select2Test() in C:\....:line 86
```

Remote Webdriver :

```
     case "remote":
         var huburl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SeleniumHubAddress"]);
         DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
         switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverBrowserCapabilities"].ToLower())
                        {
                            case "firefox":
                                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
                                break;
                            case "ie":
                                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
                                break;
                            case "chrome":
                                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("WebDriverBrowserCapabilities of \"{0}\" is not implemented for {1} mode", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverBrowserCapabilities"].ToLower(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverMode"].ToLower()));
                        }

         capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
         driver = new AdvancedRemoteWebDriver(huburl, capabilities);
         break;
     default:
         throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Comment: in yOur xpath div[.='1000'] seems wrong it should be like /div[@YOURATTRIBUTE='1000'] .. Can you post your HTML so we can provide some solution

Comment: @ShubhamJain I'm selecting by text, because all the select2 result rows have the same attributes

Comment: This code should work. Did you remove or add something?

Comment: @Guy Code is working like half of the time. I even took screenshots after every step, but there is no difference between succeeded and failed test. The problem is why test is failing randomly because of that exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Text user like below xpath:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[text()='1000']"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use explicit wait with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div"), "1000")).Click();
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to have the text "1000" before clicking on it. You can also use

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[.='1000']"))).Click();
```

Comment: I tried this, but in 5 times it failed once. Maybe there is something wrong about remote webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Selenium for C# has several pre-constructed parameters for the `WebDriverWait.Until()` method. So you need not call `FindElement()`.

Maybe you can try something like

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[.='1000']")));
```

If this doesn't work either, then maybe your XPath string is not correct (I just copied it from your question into my answer).